# Swift class conformance of multiple protocols (XCode 7, iOS 9, Swift 2.1)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, protocols, xcode7

How can I make a Swift class to conform multiple protocols like in ObjC?

I get an error saying

> Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'Protocol_A'
>
> Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'Protocol_B'
>
> Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'Protocol_C'
>
> Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'Protocol_D'

I was expecting Swift protocol:ing to work easy and similarly to Objective C but apparently Apple have geniuses. Oh well.

**EDIT:**
Apparently the problem does not occur when the protocol is empty.
But when I add a `func` to one of the protocols, the error occurs again.

Here's my example-code:

```
protocol Protocol_A {
    func someFunc()
}

protocol Protocol_B {
}

protocol Protocol_C {
}

protocol Protocol_D {
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, Protocol_A, Protocol_B, Protocol_C, Protocol_D {
}
```

Comment: Your code just works well with my XCode 7 & swift 2.

Comment: Your Protocols do not have any methods (Except A which you have not implemented).

Comment: @Leo you are right. It works, but only if the protocols are empty. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Create the function inside your class. After that it will confirm

Comment: @MitchellCurrie how do I do that? In `ObjC` the methods only need to exist in the protocol, but not inside the class that conforms to that protocol unless that class is going to receive a call on the method.

Comment: It's a bit silly having an empty protocol. I mean not useful.

Comment: I agree, however that was just test-code. i didn't want to show my actual code. I'm in fact not even allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implments the protocol function in the class

For example

```
protocol Protocol_A {
func someFunc()
}

protocol Protocol_B {
    func someFuncB()
}

protocol Protocol_C {
}

protocol Protocol_D {
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, Protocol_A, Protocol_B, Protocol_C, Protocol_D {
func someFunc() {

}
func someFuncB() {

}
}
```

If you want function to be optional

```
@objc protocol Protocol_A {
   optional func someFunc()
}
```

Comment: This is correct, however `ObjC` does not require one to do that. The method does not need to exist inside the conformer. I guess I'm the genius here haha

Comment: You can set method to be optional as well,see my update. It is the style of swift,either you declare it as optional,either the conformer should offer the function

Comment: That's just confusing, they should've just allowed a definition somewhere, like `protocol optional`.